# JBoss Task scheduling: pass argument to method

Tags: java, jboss, scheduling, jboss5.x

I'm trying to get a scheduler working in JBoss as 5.

So far, I've created my own MBean (it works) and I created my scheduler like this:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.scheduler.Scheduler"
          name=":service=Scheduler,name=SchedulableMBeanExample">
  <depends>user:service=Print</depends>
  <attribute name="StartAtStartup">true</attribute>
  <attribute name="SchedulableMBean">user:service=Print</attribute>
  <attribute name="SchedulableMBeanMethod">print(java.lang.String)</attribute>
  <attribute name="InitialStartDate">NOW</attribute>
  <attribute name="SchedulePeriod">10000</attribute>
  <attribute name="InitialRepetitions">10</attribute>
  <attribute name="FixedRate">true</attribute></mbean>
```

It works, but the main question is how can I specify the string I want to pass as an argument to my method?

I've searched but the only closer thing I've found is this attribute : "SchedulableArguments" but this works only for the constructor.

Thanks for your help guys.

Laurent.

Answer (score 0):

After installing an MBean in JBoss you can configure MBean parameters by JBoss jmx-console a web interface to configure JBoss.

See this article from JBoss wiki: [ExampleHelloWorldService](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExampleHelloWorldService)

Answer (score 0):

You're halfway there; you've got the right attribute -- `SchedulableMBeanMethod` -- which allows a list of parameters, but only specific ones.  According to the [jboss 4 guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r1/html/ch10.html), your options for parameters are:

- NOTIFICATION which will be replaced by the timers notification instance (javax.management.Notification)
- DATE which will be replaced by the date of the notification call (java.util.Date)
- REPETITIONS which will be replaced by the number of remaining repetitions (long)
- SCHEDULER_NAME which will be replaced by the ObjectName of the Scheduler
- Any fully qualified class name which the Scheduler will set to null.

  If you need to pass anything else, I think your best bet is to add a method to your mbean just to calculate & pass parameters to your working function.

Guessing that you want to print the current date, you might set:

```
  <attribute name="SchedulableMBeanMethod">scheduledPrint(DATE)</attribute>
```

And define `scheduledPrint` to format a date string and call your `print` method.